# LibreOffice Calc - Perform operation on every nth cell

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to copy every 10th cell from a column of several thousand. Is this possible?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211062/copy-every-nth-line-from-one-sheet-to-another

Comment: That does help! I couldn't get the accepted solution to work, but the data sorting trick in the second answer works great. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked.

Comment: @Mitch I recommend slightly expanding your comment with the link into an answer, so bessman can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a question on stack-overflow, that addresses a similar problem.  I believe that one or more of the answers might have the solution that you're looking for.  The top 2 answers I think might do it for you.  The first answer involves a formula, and the second one involves data sorting in a certain way.

Quoted from the Stack-Overflow answer:

> In A1 of your new sheet, put this:
>
> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0)
>
> ... and copy down. If you start somewhere other than row 1, change
>   ROW() to ROW(A1) or some other cell on row 1, then copy down again.
>
> If you want to copy the nth line but multiple columns, use the
>   formula:
>
> =OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1,(ROW()-1)*7,0)
>
> This can be copied right too.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211062/copy-every-nth-line-from-one-sheet-to-another) to see the question on Stack-Overflow.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.